# XQuery using predicates: difference between return and for

Tags: xpath, xquery, basex

I thought that these two xquery expressions were equivalent:

```
for $x
  in doc("hamlet.xml")//LINE[../SPEAKER = "HAMLET"]
  return $x[../preceding-sibling::SPEECH[1]/SPEAKER = "MARCELLUS"]

for $x
  in doc("hamlet.xml")//LINE[../SPEAKER = "HAMLET"][../preceding-sibling::SPEECH[1]/SPEAKER = "MARCELLUS"]
  return $x
```

The difference is the predicate which is first used in the return, and after in the for. Why the output is not the same ?

(https://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/hamlet.xml)

EDIT:: I use BASEX 9.0.1.

Comment: I get the same result of 14 elements with both queries and BaseX GUI 9.0.1 and using `doc("https://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/hamlet.xml")` directly where you had `doc("hamlet.xml")`.

Comment: I don't understand. You're right. With the second query, if i use doc("https://www.ibiblio.org/xml/examples/shakespeare/hamlet.xml") i got the same output as you. If i use doc("hamlet.xml"), i got more that 50 elements.

Comment: I guess you have to wait until someone from the BaseX team explains that, looks like a query on a document in the database gives a different result, which I think is likely a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I agree this is a bug, which is caused by an optimization step for utilizing the text index (https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1573). A bug fix is available (http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/); 9.0.2 will be available by end of May.

Answer (score 1):

They look the same to me.

For the first query Saxon gives

```
<LINE>I am very glad to see you. Good even, sir.</LINE>
<LINE>But what, in faith, make you from Wittenberg?</LINE>
<LINE>Did you not speak to it?</LINE>
<LINE>Arm'd, say you?</LINE>
<LINE>From top to toe?</LINE>
<LINE>Then saw you not his face?</LINE>
<LINE>Hold off your hands.</LINE>
<LINE>How say you, then; would heart of man once think it?</LINE>
<LINE>But you'll be secret?</LINE>
<LINE>There's ne'er a villain dwelling in all Denmark</LINE>
<LINE>But he's an arrant knave.</LINE>
<LINE>Nay, but swear't.</LINE>
<LINE>Upon my sword.</LINE>
<LINE>Indeed, upon my sword, indeed.</LINE>
```

For the second query Saxon gives:

```
<LINE>I am very glad to see you. Good even, sir.</LINE>
<LINE>But what, in faith, make you from Wittenberg?</LINE>
<LINE>Did you not speak to it?</LINE>
<LINE>Arm'd, say you?</LINE>
<LINE>From top to toe?</LINE>
<LINE>Then saw you not his face?</LINE>
<LINE>Hold off your hands.</LINE>
<LINE>How say you, then; would heart of man once think it?</LINE>
<LINE>But you'll be secret?</LINE>
<LINE>There's ne'er a villain dwelling in all Denmark</LINE>
<LINE>But he's an arrant knave.</LINE>
<LINE>Nay, but swear't.</LINE>
<LINE>Upon my sword.</LINE>
<LINE>Indeed, upon my sword, indeed.</LINE>
```

What differences are you seeing, and what XQuery implementation are you using?

Comment: I use BaseX.  In BaseX, the first query returns 14 lines (same output as you). The second one returns more than 50 lines. It's maybe a bug of BaseX.